# Is it possible to change xterm "color table" at runtime?

Tags: colors, terminal, xterm

I have my xterm inherit RGB values for its "color table" from an X resource file. As far as I understand, xterm does not just support 256 colors - it supports 256 color references pointing each to a 24-bit RGB space color, correct?

I would like to be able to reset the colors themselves, for example change the color with index 10 to an RGB value `#ff8000` or something.

I don't even know if I have got my concepts right here. If I have, is it possible to change entries in this "color table" at runtime - for the current terminal window? Or one can only do so with `xrdb` for next opened terminal instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this actually works  (my xterm here isn't compiled with 256 color support!) but the xterm control sequence reference:

http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Look under "Operating System Controls"

P s = 4 ; c ; spec → Change Color Number c to the color specified by spec. This can be a name or RGB specification as per XParseColor. Any number of c name pairs may be given. The color numbers correspond to the ANSI colors 0-7, their bright versions 8-15, and if supported, the remainder of the 88-color or 256-color table.

OSC is \033], so try this out:

```
echo -n -e '\033]4;7;red\007'
```

should change color #7 to red if it works.

Comment: Thanks, trying this right now. Am I correct in my assumption that xterm supports 256 "true" colors?

Comment: Worked like a charm! `echo -n -e '\033]4;7;#ff8000\007'` changed the color at index `7` (don't confuse with `007`) to `#ff8000` (a bright orange).

Comment: Also, I think even if your xterm is compiled with only `N` color support, you should be able to set actual color values for these "colors" (indices, really) in range of `0` to `N - 1`. In your case `0 - 15`.

Comment: Oh cool, you're right, it does work even without 256 colors! But yeah, it should also work for all 256 colors, can be set to anything.